# Cordova with command sudo + action

Tags: cordova, action, sudo

I have a small question at the level of cordova ...

For some days when I work with cordova I have to execute the command sudo also to perform actions .....

Example if I execute this command

Cordova platform add ios

I have this error message ....

=>

/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:53
                throw err;
                ^

Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/Users/Tropico/.config/configstore/insight-cordova.json'
You don't have access to this file.

```
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:558:18)
at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:468:33)
at Configstore.get (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:34:26)
at Configstore (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/node_modules/configstore/index.js:27:44)
at new Insight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/insight/lib/index.js:38:34)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/src/telemetry.js:37:15)
at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
```

MacBook-Pro-de-Tropico-2:Onlssaf Tropico$

But if I run the command with sudo

Sudo cordova platform add ios

It works very well

I wonder if it's dramatic if I always use the SUDO command

?

Thank you

Comment: Believe this is a problem with permissions from when npm was installed. 
 Check out this for a few work arounds: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: Hello,

thank you for your reply,

I do the command line

I do not understand this step

  Source ~ / .profile

I have to bypass this step with the ENV command

But once I've done it all ...

When I run my app I still have the error?

I am still stuck with this problem ...


I would like to know if there is a command that allows any delete ...

Npm, cordova, ionic

Then I can start over step by step

can be?

Thank you

Comment: @PECNET Hi did you got the Solution I am having the same help me if you got the Solution . Please